# Javascript library to gracefully downgrade custom elements in HTML at runtime

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I would like to say

```
<html>
<body>
<mytag foo="bar">blah</mytag>
</body>
</html>
```

And define somewhere else how a `<mytag>` should behave. But for older browsers that do not play nicely with custom tags, I would like to just load a js library in the browser and have it automatically rewrite the above code as say

```
<html>
<body>
<div data-mytag data-foo="bar">blah</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obviously this functionality could be hacked together in an hour, but I would prefer to use a tiny library that someone has written, for the sake of convention and possibly handy features. Do you know of one? Note: please don't reply about why I shouldn't use custom tags.

Comment: Did you try Googling it? http://www.x-tags.org/ looks like a possible solution

Comment: But be aware, you aren't looking for JS to downgrade to `data-mytag`. That's HTML5, which isn't supported in older browsers either: http://html5readiness.com/

Comment: @John, `[data-*]` attributes are backwards compatible.

Comment: @zzzzBov Wow, that does seem to be true. Never knew that, thanks. Just need to make sure to have HTML5 as your `DOCTYPE`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, maybe something like

```
<mytag>yo</mytag> 
<script>
var map = {
    MYTAG: function(s){
        // surround content with stars
        return '**'+s+'**';
    }
}
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName('*')).forEach(function(tag){ 
    // note on some IE versions you cant set innerHTML directly
    if(map[tag.tagName]) tag.innerHTML = map[tag.tagName](tag.innerHTML);
})
</script>
```

For changing element tags at runtime, I can't recall if that's possible.  People may cringe, but I'd maybe take the entire document.body.innerHTML replace it using regexes and reset it.  If I knew I was the only creator of the HTML content that may take care of it..